# C program randomly inserting random name of function into my array

Tags: c, arrays, gcc, memory

I have the following program that converts decimal to binary:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    printf("Number (decimal): ");
    int no;
    scanf("%d", &no);

    char bin[64];
    while (no > 0) {
        for (int i = strlen(bin); i > 0; i--) {
            bin[i] = bin[i - 1];
        }

        int bit = no % 2;
        char digit = bit + '0';
        bin[0] = digit;

        no /= 2;
    }

    printf("%s", bin);

    return 0;
}
```

The program works correctly, but randomly the string "`ttime__vdso_get`" gets appended on the end.

The numbers that make it happen are different every time I compile.

1: `1`

2: `01ttime_vsdo_get`

3: `10ttime_vsdo_get`

It becomes a little different when the numbers get bigger:

100039: `11000011011000111ttime__vdso_getm@`

10000000000000000000000000000: `ttime`

---

What is happening?

If I had to diagnose it I'd say that I've managed to make a compiling program that's pulling memory from the wrong places. I don't know how how I managed to do it, though.

I'm using GCC, if it matters.

Comment: strlen does not return an int.

Comment: `bin` is not initialized. The effect of calling `strlen` on it is undefined.

Comment: @Michi That isn't the problem, I've gotten the length other ways and it's still happening.

Comment: initialize bin with `char bin[64]="";` since all 64 characters of the string is not changed during the program, the garbage value which was stored initially wouldnt change. and hence appearing in the output

Comment: @Jackhasakeyboard I never said that is your problem.

Comment: @JackHasaKeyboard storing the value returned from `strlen()` (which is a `size_t` value) in an `int` is a problem insofar as it is bad coding practice and should be generating a warning at compilation. Heed compiler warnings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do `char bin[64] = "";`, never forget that a valid string is nul terminatedM@��M@.

And `strlen()` return an `size_t` !

I can also advice you to use `char bin[sizeof no * CHAR_BIT + 1] = "";` that will use a correct maximum size for your string.

Answer (score 0):

It may be because of this line of code :

```
for (int i = strlen(bin); i > 0; i--) {
        bin[i] = bin[i - 1];
    }
```

Try replacing `strlen(bin)` with `63`.

It may also be a good idea to initialize your array `bin` with 0s.

Answer (score 0):

try filling varible
char bin[64] 
with 0